# Malaysia to Thailand and again Malaysia Visit

Tags: visas, thailand, malaysia

I am from Nepal, i planing to visit Malaysia, Thailand and Singapore. My plan first i visit Malaysia stay 3 days and go Thailand by land stay 1 days and again return malaysia by land and go Singapore by land stay 1 days and again back Malaysia (KL) and return home country.

I am confused here i have 3 countries visa. From Malaysia i go Thailand and return Malaysia that time i need apply new visa again or previous visa work? same as from Singapore to malaysia?

Please guideline.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a multiple entry visa for Malaysia, as each time you enter or re-enter Malaysia counts as a new entry irregardless of how long you visit for or how long you leave the country for.

Visa details: http://www.kln.gov.my/web/npl_kathmandu/requirement_foreigner

You need a visa to visit Thailand as well, which needs to be obtained in advance.  Nepali citizens do not qualify for VOA like Indian citizens.

Is there a reason (other than collecting passport stamps) for your one day visit to Thailand?  Seems like a lot of visa expense and headaches for a whirlwind visit.